# how to consume wcf rest service with windows authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, wcf-rest, wcf-rest-contrib

I am using webHttpbinding configuration for WCF Rest service.

```
 <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="RestBinding" closeTimeout="10:01:00" openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>

          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
```

And I have specified below endpointBehaviors

```
 <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="customBehavior" type="XXX" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointBehaviour">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <customBehavior />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="endpointBehaviourForRestService">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <customBehavior/>
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

How to consume this service at client side after hosting this in IIS?

Currently we are getting below error while trying to access this at client side by

```
string returnValue = webClient.UploadString("http://localhost:55107/Service1.svc/methodname", "POST", data);
```

**Error:**

```
System.Net.WebException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Also we are unable to add this as service reference in client project.

Please share your thoughts if any on this.

Comment: string returnValue = webClient.UploadString("http://localhost:55107/Service1.svc/methodname", "POST", data);

Comment: "below error". But there's no error shown. Or any meaningful code.

Comment: @Annapurna frame the question properly

Comment: formatted the question and updated more details.Could you please review once again.

Comment: it's saying the user account you're running your client code under doesn't have permission to call that service

Comment: I am also having same issue. Did you solve it...